# How to check if ellipse is outside background Image drawn with Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I can always check by looking at the co-ordinates and comparing with Image, of ellipse shape, but it fails when ellipse is at the corner.

I have tried using intersectWith method, it only works with bounding box, not the actual border of the shape.

This is the scenario I need it to work to be able to check if ellipse is outside of the background Image, not. bounding box.

[image]

Comment: You could check the corner for inclusion in the ellipse: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76463

Comment: Is there anyway I can check if backgroundImage is intersecting with the actual shape, not bounding Box ?